# MySQLDump To Export Data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way that I can generate a MySQLDump to either insert new data or update existing data?

I haven't tried anything as of yet, well that's not true... I've tried SQLYog and phpMyAdmin, and both do not seem to have the option to do this...

Comment: not really. you can provide "where" clauses as an arg to mysqldump to limit what you're dumping, but it's not really intended for partial dumps in the way you want.

Comment: What about `REPLACE`  would that `REPLACE` existing data, but still insert in new data?

Comment: it should. but you'll have to make sure that dump doesn't put any "drop" commands in there, which'd nuke the original tables.

Comment: aye.   gotcha, much obliged

Comment: In my opinion is not so easy.. think about foreign keys for examples.. how can you keep them consistent?

Comment: there aren't any as far as I can see in the database... so I'm not concerned about that.  EDIT: verified, there are 0 foreign keys.